# how to store files in phone memory when there is no sdcard in the device in android

Tags: android

I am new to android  can anybody help me to store files in the phone memory when there is no sdcard .How can I see after storing the file in the phone memory

for any help Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Split your questions into separate posts. It makes things clearer. :-)